# How points are awarded in stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

I posted a question today in stackoverflow. I learnt that i got 3 points for that question . Couldn't quite find out, how i got those points, as I didn't find any up vote. How did I earn those points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/988871/xavi-valero?tab=reputation) page, use the *by time* or *by post* view.

You got one upvote and one downvote on [Strange behavior of xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959260/strange-behavior-of-xcode)